# Compare fields within relationship on Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models, `route` and `stop`.
A `route` can have several `stop`, each `stop` have a `name` and a `number`. On same `route`, `stop.number` are unique.

## The problem:

I need to search which `route` has two different `stops` and one `stop.number` is less than the other `stop.number`

## Consider the following models:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Stop(models.Model):
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=45)
```

## And the following data:

**Stop** table

```
| id | route_id | number | location |
|----|----------|--------|----------|
| 1  | 1        | 1      | 'A'      |
| 2  | 1        | 2      | 'B'      |
| 3  | 1        | 3      | 'C'      |
| 4  | 2        | 1      | 'C'      |
| 5  | 2        | 2      | 'B'      |
| 6  | 2        | 3      | 'A'      |
```

### In example:

Given two locations 'A' and 'B', search which routes have both `location` and `A.number` is less than `B.number`

With the previous data, it should match `route id 1` and not `route id 2`

### On raw SQL, this works with a single query:

```
SELECT 
    `route`.id 
FROM 
    `route` 
    LEFT JOIN `stop` stop_from ON stop_from.`route_id` = `route`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `stop` stop_to ON stop_to.`route_id` = `route`.`id` 
WHERE 
    stop_from.`stop_location_id` = 'A'
    AND stop_to.`stop_location_id` = 'B'
    AND stop_from.stop_number < stop_to.stop_number
```

Is this possible to do with one single query on Django ORM as well?

Answer (score 0):

Generally ORM frameworks like Django ORM, SQLAlchemy and even Hibernate is not design to autogenerate most efficient query. There is a way to write this query only using Model objects, however, since I had similar issue, I would suggest to use raw query for more complex queries. Following is link for Django raw query:

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/]

Although, you can write your query in many ways but something like following could help.

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT 
    `route`.id 
FROM 
    `route` 
    LEFT JOIN `stop` stop_from ON stop_from.`route_id` = `route`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `stop` stop_to ON stop_to.`route_id` = `route`.`id` 
WHERE 
    stop_from.`stop_location_id` = %s
    AND stop_to.`stop_location_id` = %s
    AND stop_from.stop_number < stop_to.stop_number", ['A', 'B'])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

hope this helps.

Comment: RAW query is my current approach, but I think that exists some better way to accomplish this.

Comment: I agree, there is always a better solution exists. However, if you connect the model object to get the query on object level, there is no guarantee that ORM (Django ORM, or other ORMs) generate one query and send that to database. However, more important is that usually that query is not most efficient query. Don't take me wrong Django ORM is one of the best ORM I every work with (as good as Hibernate), but generally goal of ORMs is to auto generate query and convert result to object not most efficient query.